# CUDA 10.1 deb install for Ubuntu 18.04 fails to initialize NVML

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, cuda

Ubuntu 18.04 with `4.18.0-15-generic`.

I've been following along https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Install-CUDA-10-together-with-9-2-on-Ubuntu-18-04-with-support-for-NVIDIA-20XX-Turing-GPUs-1236/

After a bunch of issues and using `lightdm`, I was finally able to get a running system with CUDA and `nvidia-smi`... using the runfile. I did a `sudo nvidia-uninstall` and re-installed CUDA from the .deb in order to get `prime-select`. But then `nvidia-smi` fails with `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`?

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-418:amd64                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-418                            418.67-0ubuntu1                              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-418:amd64                     418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-418:amd64                      418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-418:amd64                      418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-418:amd64                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-418:amd64                          418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-418:amd64                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-418                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-418                                 418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-418                               418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-418                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-418                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                 418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.8.2                                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-418                                418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418                   418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where this started working but!

1. `sudo prime-select nvidia` and switch to nvidia graphics

If this doesn't work and you've used the runfile to install CUDA before, what I actually did was:

1. Uninstall CUDA and all drivers with `apt-get purge nvidia-*` and something similar for `cuda-` I think. There might have been a random `libcuda` or something, I forget the name, sorry. Also go to `/usr/local/cuda` and try to find an uninstaller because there should be files left over, and run that script.
2. Install CUDA from runfile again.
3. Uninstall using `nvidia-uninstall` or whatever uninstall command it's supposed to be. Should be on `PATH`. Go through instructions and remove everything.
4. Install CUDA from .deb. And *do not* update `cuda` or `nvidia` or whatever.
5. Install `prime-select`, do step `0` and you should be okay.